# Painless way to show simple inequality over whole number

Tags: lean

I have the following state:

```
a : ℕ,
a_1 : ℕ,
nltm : of_nat a_1 + 1 < of_nat a + 1
⊢ of_nat a_1 < of_nat a
```

Do note that `of_nat` constructs `Z`.

Is there a painless way of discharging the goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `lt_of_lt_add_right`:

```
open int
example (a a_1 : ℕ) (nltm : of_nat a_1 + 1 < of_nat a + 1) : of_nat a_1 < of_nat a :=
lt_of_add_lt_add_right nltm
```

Learning the [Lean naming conventions](https://github.com/leanprover/mathlib/blob/master/style.md) is very helpful for finding such lemmas.

Comment: Oh my, it is in oredered_group.lean. I tried using VSCode's autocompletion to find relevant lemmas, and I found order.lean and basic.lean, both having bits and pieces of lemmas available for int. So it would appear that Lean took smarter than Coq approach and there's uniform access to those via algebraic structures, and then some arbitrary  stuff lying around next to definitions just for a good measure! :) Thank you again.

Comment: ScarletAmaranth: I found the lemma by completing `lt_of_`. You shouldn't have to worry about which file the lemma is located in.